# What I'm doing wrong while installing scipy using pip3 on Mac

Tags: python, pip, scipy

Facing following issue while installing scipy 1.2.1

```
(env) sahibyar@Sahibs-MacBook-Pro services % pip3 install scipy==1.2.1 
Collecting scipy==1.2.1
  Using cached scipy-1.2.1.tar.gz (23.1 MB)
Using legacy setup.py install for scipy, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: scipy
    Running setup.py install for scipy ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/sahibyar/Dailytasks/env/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/5_/5blqbh750wsc9pc01bn0lgph0000gn/T/pip-install-lk7yk3u0/scipy/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/5_/5blqbh750wsc9pc01bn0lgph0000gn/T/pip-install-lk7yk3u0/scipy/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/5_/5blqbh750wsc9pc01bn0lgph0000gn/T/pip-record-96sbgt69/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/sahibyar/Dailytasks/env/include/site/python3.7/scipy
         cwd: /private/var/folders/5_/5blqbh750wsc9pc01bn0lgph0000gn/T/pip-install-lk7yk3u0/scipy/
    Complete output (107 lines):
    /private/var/folders/5_/5blqbh750wsc9pc01bn0lgph0000gn/T/pip-install-lk7yk3u0/scipy/setup.py:114: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
      import imp
    
    Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
    with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:
    
      - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                               release)
      - `pip install scipy`   (last SciPy release on PyPI)
    
    
    Running from scipy source directory.
    lapack_opt_info:
    lapack_mkl_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/Users/sahibyar/Dailytasks/env/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    openblas_lapack_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['/Users/sahibyar/Dailytasks/env/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    openblas_clapack_info:
      libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['/Users/sahibyar/Dailytasks/env/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    flame_info:
      libraries flame not found in ['/Users/sahibyar/Dailytasks/env/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    accelerate_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    atlas_3_10_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /Users/sahibyar/Dailytasks/env/lib
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /Users/sahibyar/Dailytasks/env/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    atlas_3_10_info:
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /Users/sahibyar/Dailytasks/env/lib
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in /Users/sahibyar/Dailytasks/env/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /Users/sahibyar/Dailytasks/env/lib
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /Users/sahibyar/Dailytasks/env/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    atlas_info:
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /Users/sahibyar/Dailytasks/env/lib
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /Users/sahibyar/Dailytasks/env/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    lapack_info:
      libraries lapack not found in ['/Users/sahibyar/Dailytasks/env/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    /Users/sahibyar/Dailytasks/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1858: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
    lapack_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    /Users/sahibyar/Dailytasks/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1858: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/5_/5blqbh750wsc9pc01bn0lgph0000gn/T/pip-install-lk7yk3u0/scipy/setup.py", line 492, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "/private/var/folders/5_/5blqbh750wsc9pc01bn0lgph0000gn/T/pip-install-lk7yk3u0/scipy/setup.py", line 488, in setup_package
        setup(**metadata)
      File "/Users/sahibyar/Dailytasks/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 135, in setup
        config = configuration()
      File "/private/var/folders/5_/5blqbh750wsc9pc01bn0lgph0000gn/T/pip-install-lk7yk3u0/scipy/setup.py", line 395, in configuration
        raise NotFoundError(msg)
    numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: No lapack/blas resources found. Note: Accelerate is no longer supported.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/sahibyar/Dailytasks/env/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/5_/5blqbh750wsc9pc01bn0lgph0000gn/T/pip-install-lk7yk3u0/scipy/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/5_/5blqbh750wsc9pc01bn0lgph0000gn/T/pip-install-lk7yk3u0/scipy/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/5_/5blqbh750wsc9pc01bn0lgph0000gn/T/pip-record-96sbgt69/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/sahibyar/Dailytasks/env/include/site/python3.7/scipy Check the logs for full command output.
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.1.1; however, version 21.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/Users/sahibyar/Dailytasks/env/bin/python3.7 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
(env) sahibyar@Sahibs-MacBook-Pro services %
```

Comment: What happens if you run "pip install wheel"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems your pip aversion in mac is too old, you need to upgrade pip first

```
 pip install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 0):

If you having issue with PIP you can try following ways

Download the dispenses  directly from site

https://pypi.org/project/scipy/#files

later install directly wheel with pip

```
pip install wheelname.whl`
```

`
Example

```
pip install scipy-1.5.4-cp38-cp38-macosx_11_0_x86_64.whl
```

Along with this check below thread

https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/13102#issuecomment-850882851

Comment: Part of the error message is "package 'wheel' is not installed," so trying to directly install a .whl file may not work.

Comment: Yes, maybe trying older Wheels may work I think...& below GitHub thread I've mentioned  is completely related to this following  mentioned error we are talking about...